# How do you import a .gltf model in ar.js?

Tags: three.js, gltf, ar.js

i'm kinda new to working with ar.js. I really wanted to see what I could do with it. Well, I ran into a wall, I'm trying to import a custom gltf model to ar.js (the version that uses three.js instead of a-frame) but the model does not even appear. I don't know if i'm doing the import correctly as I haven't found an example online. I know my model works because I tried three.js and GLTFLoader beforehand and was succesfull. I don't what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you post your code? are you serving it?

Comment: Please update the question with relevant informations: type of marker used, sample of code, version fo AR.js, tested devices. You say "haven't found an example online" did you read the https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/README.md and the official docs https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/ ? there are some examples on this subject.